# 403 forbidden error when trying to install script on sub-directory

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, .htaccess, laravel, http-status-code-403

I have my own server which I run a few sites from. I have sub-directories that link to full domains (/music points to -> www.music-site.com)

My problem is I am getting a 403 forbidden error with a script I have installed to another sub-directory.

.htaccess file is as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

If it makes any difference, the script I am trying to install is based on laravel and bootstrap frameworks.

Does anyone know the issue?

Comment: What is the script? Why is apache involved? What were you trying to do when you got the 403? There is not enough information to help you.

Comment: The script was one I purchased off Envato. The guide that came with it states, "Once you've entered your database details, simply open up http://www.siteurl/install and follow on-screen instructions to finish the installation." 

There is no "install" directory including in the package which, according to the developer, is correct.

Comment: After configuring the database details, I point to siteurl/install and I am getting the 403 error.

Comment: that is still not enough information. Is this .htaccess file in the same directory as what I assume is called your `install.php` file? Do any other .php files in the same directory work? I also don't see anything here that is related to mysql, why do you think that's relevant to the problem (if it's not, let's remove that tag again)

Comment: @suge1w Did you check the permissions of the script? usually you should set it to 644

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your replies. Mike: *That tag will be removed. There is no install.php file. Everything seems to run through a folder called "app". Those familiar with Laravel might know a thing or two about this?? Even changing the permissions of that folder to 777 does nothing! @nmos I have tried this. One thing I should mention, I tried typing in robots.txt of the sub-directory and still received a 403 error! With no .htaccess, the error changed to a 404!

Comment: Have you had checked routes and are you 100% sure that you've installed this script properly? I'm not familiar with laravel but I assume that as any other framework it has some route settings and its own app structure. When I have 403 errors it's in 99% cases caused exactly by what I've mentioned.

Comment: @Zentoaku, checked routes? I am 100% sure I have installed it correctly. All it consists of is uploading the contents of the package to your server and creating a database. I was thinking about a htaccess file in the root. I have one as follows "

# Use PHP5.3 as default
#AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php


<Files 403.shtml>
order allow,deny
allow from all
</Files>

deny from 72.219.142.117
deny from 222.161.213.115
deny from 109.251.107.232
deny from 65.32.93.229"

Comment: Do you think a root .htaccess file would cause 403 errors on sub-directories?

Comment: Maybe. You can check "RewriteBase /" rule if it helps. IN: http://laravel.com/docs/quick you have "Route::get('users', function()
{
    return View::make('users');
});", that's what I meant by routes.

Comment: @Zentoaku, just tried that and still nothing!

Comment: Could you add script file structure, content of index.php (if any) and IndexController (if any)? Sorry if that offends you but I have to ask: are you installing this script in laravel project or is laravel included at least?

Comment: @Zentoaku, thanks for your help. I have managed to get the script installed and everything works well except when I upload an image I get an error. Upload directory has the correct permissions but I continue to get "object Object" error. Do you know what could be causing this?

Comment: @suge1w imposibble to say without looking on code source and full stacktrace